# postgres: dynamic subquery in join filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently trying to define a dynamic query in Postgres. Essentially the filtering done by a subquery used in the Join depends on the results for each row. The idea is that each “name” in the query will only return one project_id based on a specific set of parameters.

The basic query without any filtering:

```
SELECT a.name, rproj.raproject_id, rproj.current_status, rproj.create_date
FROM focalpoint fp
JOIN agl_asset a ON a.serial_number::text = fp."RoutineNumber"::text
JOIN agl_raproject AS rproj ON a.asset_id = rproj.asset_id 
JOIN agl_auditproject AS audit ON rproj.auditproject_id = audit.auditproject_id
ORDER BY a.name
```

That would return:

```
name    raproject_id        current_status      create_date
AssetA  405323966463427000  Review              24/10/2014 18:35
AssetA  405323966463460000  Review              07/10/2016 14:04
AssetA  405323966463413000  Risk Identification 28/11/2013 14:16
AssetA  405323966463413000  Closed              21/11/2013 17:33
AssetB  405323966463412000  Monitoring          15/11/2013 11:26
AssetB  405323966463427000  Review              24/10/2014 18:35
AssetB  405323966463461000  Assessment          13/10/2016 10:32
AssetB  405323966463412000  Closed              15/11/2013 11:44
```

But I only want one “project” per asset. If I was just trying to get the “newest” based on the create_date it would be:

```
SELECT a.name, rproj.raproject_id, rproj.current_status, rproj.create_date
FROM focalpoint fp
JOIN agl_asset a ON a.serial_number::text = fp."RoutineNumber"::text
JOIN agl_raproject AS rproj ON a.asset_id = rproj.asset_id AND rproj.create_date = ((SELECT max(rproj2.create_date) AS max
 FROM agl_raproject rproj2
 JOIN agl_auditproject audit ON rproj2.auditproject_id = audit.auditproject_id
 WHERE a.asset_id = rproj2.asset_id AND audit.project_type::text = 'ngERMAssessment'::text))
JOIN agl_auditproject AS audit ON rproj.auditproject_id = audit.auditproject_id
ORDER BY a.name
```

But what I need is:

1. If there’s any project, for this specific asset, where the
   current_status is “Monitoring” – Return that row
2. If not, take the newest one (as I’ve done already on the last query).

But again, only one project from raproject should be returned per asset.

EDIT:
The expected return would be:

```
name    raproject_id        current_status      create_date
AssetA  405323966463460000  Review              07/10/2016 14:04
AssetB  405323966463412000  Monitoring          15/11/2013 11:26
```

Answer (score 1):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (a.name)
    a.name, rproj.raproject_id, rproj.current_status, rproj.create_date
from
    focalpoint fp
    inner join
    agl_asset a on a.serial_number::text = fp."RoutineNumber"::text
    inner join
    agl_raproject as rproj on a.asset_id = rproj.asset_id 
    inner join
    agl_auditproject as audit on rproj.auditproject_id = audit.auditproject_id
order by a.name, rproj.current_status <> 'Monitoring', rproj.create_date desc
```

Check the `order by` requirement